# Alter the LAST_INSERT_ID() from within a TRIGGER in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, auto-increment, last-insert-id

I have a `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` which is used to calculate the `AUTO_INCREMENT` value of a column (`id_2`).

```
id_1 | id_2 | data
1    | 1    | 'a'
1    | 2    | 'b'
1    | 3    | 'c'
2    | 1    | 'a'
2    | 2    | 'b'
2    | 3    | 'c'
2    | 4    | 'a'
3    | 1    | 'b'
3    | 2    | 'c'
```

I have PRIMARY(id_1, id_2) and I am using InnoDB. Before, the table was using MyISAM and I've had no problems: `id_2` was set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`, so each new entry for `id_1` would generate new `id_2` on its own. Now, after switching to InnoDB, I have this trigger to do the same thing:

```
SET @id = NULL;
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id_2) + 1, 1) INTO @id FROM tbl WHERE id_1 = NEW.id_1;
SET NEW.id_2= @id;
```

It works perfectly, except now the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` has wrong value (it returns 0). A lot of code depends on the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` being correct. However since MySQL 5.0.12 any changes made to `LAST_INSERT_ID` within TRIGGERS are not affecting the global value. Is there any way to bypass this? I can easily set the `AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER` which changes the `LAST_INSERT_ID` by calling `LAST_INSERT_ID(NEW.id_2)`, however any client-side would get `LAST_INSERT_ID` set to 0.

Is there any working work-around to force MySQL to maintain the state of `LAST_INSERT_ID` which was changed inside the trigger? Is there any alternative, other than switching back to MyISAM which supports this out of the box or running another `SELECT max(id_2) FROM tbl WHERE id_1 = :id` as part of the transaction to ensure that the row found will be the one inserted earlier?

```
> SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl;

CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
   `id_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `id_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `data` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`,`id_2`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

**Example:**

```
INSERT INTO tbl (id_1, id_2, data) VALUES (1, NULL, 'd');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The first statement will insert the row `1    | 4    | 'd'` into the table. The second statement will return `0`, but I need it to return `4`.

As asked by [Ravinder Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/767881/ravinder-reddy), adding the short explanation about the system:

I have a table that contains **baskets**, and I have another table (`tbl`) that contains **items**. The **basket** is created by the application and is assigned an ID from `AUTO_INCREMENT` on baskets' table. The task is to insert **items** in basket with id = `id_1`, into `tbl`, assigning them a unique ID within that basket's scope. Each **item** has some `data` associated with it, which may repeat within the same **basket**. So in practice, I am trying to store all the `data` entries within a single **basket**, and then be able to refer to (and retrieve) these individual entries by their `id_1`-`id_2` pairs.

Comment: I'm a little confused, but how would you have a LAST_INSERT_ID() _before_ the INSERT is executed?  I believe LAST_INSERT_ID() is only reliable when an insert has been executed on the same client connection.  Meaning that if the application opens a connection, performs an insert, then closes the connection, you won't be able to simply open a new connection and access LAST_INSERT_ID() without having actually executed an insert on that connection prior to calling the function.

Comment: I was making the call to `LAST_INSERT_ID()` after the INSERT was completed, so after the trigger finished running. In other words, the trigger to generate the value for the second column of the two-column primary key, had no way to communicate the newly set value. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: @Xeos: Can you please add `show create table tbl` ouput to the post?

Comment: @RavinderReddy I've edited the question to include the output.

Answer (score 2):

With your table structure description, it is clear that it does not have a primary key field whose values can be auto generated. MySQL's `information_schema.tables` does not hold `auto_increment` value but `null` for those fields which are not defined `auto_increment`.

**Trigger issue**:

The code block used in your trigger body seems depending on explicit calculation and input for the id fields. It did not use the default behaviour of an `auto_increment` field.

As per [***MySQL's documentation on LAST_INSERT_ID***](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

> **LAST_INSERT_ID()** returns a BIGINT UNSIGNED (64-bit) value
>   representing the first *automatically generated* value
>   successfully inserted for an **AUTO_INCREMENT** column
>   as a result of the most recently executed INSERT statement.

It is clear that it is for *auto_increment* fields only.
None of the fields `id_1` and `id_2` are attributed `auto_increment`.
Due to the reason, though you pass `null` as input for those fields while inserting, no value will be auto generated and assigned to them.

Alter your table to set `auto_increment` to one of those `id_x` fields, and then start inserting values. One caution is that passing a value explicitly to an `auto_increment` field during insertion will cause `last_insert_id` return a `zero` or most recent auto generated value, but not the `NEW.id`. Passing a `null` or not choosing the `auto_increment` field during insertion will trigger generation of NEW value for that field and `last_insert_id` can pick and return it.

**Following example demonstrates above behaviour**:

```
mysql> drop table if exists so_q27476005;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table so_q27476005( i int primary key );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)
```

Following statement shows next applicable `auto_increment` value for a field.

```
mysql> select auto_increment
    ->   from information_schema.tables
    ->  where table_name='so_q27476005';
+----------------+
| auto_increment |
+----------------+
|           NULL |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let us try inserting a `null` value into the field.

```
mysql> insert into so_q27476005 values( null );
ERROR 1048 (23000): Column 'i' cannot be null
```

Above statement failed because input was into a `not null primary key` field but not attributed for `auto_increment`. Only for `auto_increment` fields, you can pass `null` inputs.

Now let us see the behaviour of `last_insert_id`:

```
mysql> insert into so_q27476005 values( 1 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

As the input was explicit and also the field is not attributed for `auto_increment`,
call for `last_insert_id` resulted a `0`. Note that, this can also be some value else,
if there was another `insert` call for any other `auto_increment` field of another table,
in the same database connection session.

Let us see the records in the table.

```
mysql> select * from so_q27476005;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, let us apply `auto_increment` to the field `i`.

```
mysql> alter table so_q27476005 change column i i int auto_increment;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.66 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Following statement shows next applicable `auto_increment` value for the field `i`.

```
mysql> select auto_increment
    ->   from information_schema.tables
    ->  where table_name='so_q27476005';
+----------------+
| auto_increment |
+----------------+
|              2 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can cross check that the `last_insert_id` still is the same.

```
mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Let us insert a `null` value into the field `i`.

```
mysql> insert into so_q27476005 values( null );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.03 sec)
```

It succeeded though passing a `null` to a `primary key` field,
because the field is attributed for `auto_increment`.
Let us see which value was generated and inserted.

```
mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the next applicable `auto_increment` value for the field `i` is:

```
mysql> select auto_increment
    ->   from information_schema.tables
    ->  where table_name='so_q27476005';
+----------------+
| auto_increment |
+----------------+
|              3 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from so_q27476005;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
+---+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now, let us observe how `last_insert_id` results when explicit input is given for the field.

```
mysql> insert into so_q27476005 values( 3 );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)

mysql> select * from so_q27476005;
+---+
| i |
+---+
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
+---+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You can see that `last_insert_id` did not capture the value due to explicit input.
But, information schema do registered next applicable value.

```
mysql> select auto_increment
    ->   from information_schema.tables
    ->  where table_name='so_q27476005';
+----------------+
| auto_increment |
+----------------+
|              4 |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Now, let us observe how `last_insert_id` results when input for the field is auto/implicit.

```
mysql> insert into so_q27476005 values( null );
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.10 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                4 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Hope, these details help you.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed explanation. I am having a problem with setting the `id_2` column to auto-increment. I get `Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`. My situation is that I know the value of `id_1` (which is defined by the application), but I do not know the value of `id_2`. So for each unique `id_1`, I need to have `id_2` auto-increment. So the column that I'd want to
have auto-increment is `id_2`.

Comment: Error message is pretty clear. you can have only one *`auto_increment`* field per table. I suggest you re-frame your question as a new post. explain what you actually want.

Comment: I've added a brief description of the system that uses this table to the question.

Comment: @Xeos: as per your description, tables have parent child relation. To be more clear, can you add `show create table <table_name>` on all related tables you want to work with? you better use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) to define tables and their data and then run few queries.